El elemento "Select" de ShadCN no muestra la seleccion correctamente en NextJS 14
estoy teniendo un problema con un componente de React en mi proyecto de Next.js.
El componente obtiene el ID del contacto desde la URL y carga los datos correspondientes en un formulario, permitiendo que el usuario los edite fácilmente. Sin embargo, tengo un inconveniente con el elemento . Inicialmente, el valor predeterminado se carga correctamente, pero al intentar cambiar la selección, el  se queda en blanco y no actualiza su valor como debería.
Si alguien mas ya le ha pasado y puede ayudarme con esto porfavor.
Componente:
'use client'
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input"
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label"
import { Select, SelectContent, SelectItem, SelectTrigger, SelectValue } from "@/components/ui/select"
import { Card, CardContent, CardHeader, CardTitle } from "@/components/ui/card"
import { User, Phone, ArrowLeft, MapPin, Building, Users, X, Mail } from 'lucide-react'
import ButtonTheme from "@/app/components/global/ButtonTheme"
import { postData } from "@/lib/methods"
import Link from "next/link"


const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget)
    const formEntries = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())
    console.log('Form submitted:', formEntries)
    
}

const organizationsData = [
    { id: 1, nombre: "Organización Alpha", telefono: "555-1234", correo: "contacto@alpha.com" },
    { id: 2, nombre: "Beta Solutions", telefono: "555-5678", correo: "info@beta.com" },
    { id: 3, nombre: "Gamma Corp", telefono: "555-9101", correo: "support@gamma.com" },
    { id: 4, nombre: "Delta Group", telefono: "555-1213", correo: "sales@delta.com" },
    { id: 5, nombre: "Epsilon Enterprises", telefono: "555-1415", correo: "contact@epsilon.com" },
    { id: 6, nombre: "Zeta Innovations", telefono: "555-1617", correo: "hello@zeta.com" },
    { id: 7, nombre: "Eta Solutions", telefono: "555-1819", correo: "info@eta.com" },
    { id: 8, nombre: "Theta Technologies", telefono: "555-2021", correo: "support@theta.com" },
    { id: 9, nombre: "Iota Ventures", telefono: "555-2223", correo: "hello@iota.com" },
    { id: 10, nombre: "Kappa Labs", telefono: "555-2425", correo: "contact@kappa.com" }
];

const contactos = [
    { id: 1, correo: 'juan@gmail.com', nombre: 'Juan Pérez', telefono: '555-1234', organizacion: 1, estado: 'activo' },
    { id: 2, correo: 'mari@gmail.com', nombre: 'María López', telefono: '555-5678', organizacion: 2, estado: 'activo' },
    { id: 3, correo: 'carlos@gmail.com', nombre: 'Carlos García', telefono: '555-9012', organizacion: 3, estado: 'activo' },
    { id: 4, correo: 'ana@gmail.com', nombre: 'Ana González', telefono: '555-3456', organizacion: 4, estado: 'inactivo' },
    { id: 5, correo: 'pedro@gmail.com', nombre: 'Pedro Martínez', telefono: '555-7890', organizacion: 5, estado: 'activo' },
    { id: 6, correo: 'sofia@gmail.com', nombre: 'Sofía Fernández', telefono: '555-1122', organizacion: 6, estado: 'inactivo' }
]

export default function page({ params }) {
    const contactoActual = contactos.find((c) => c.id == params.id);

    return (
        <div className="container mx-auto px-8 py-8">
            
            <Link href="/contactos/personas" className="flex items-center text-principal-200 mb-6">
                <ArrowLeft className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                Volver a Contactos
            </Link>
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-6">Editar Contacto - {params.id}</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="space-y-6">
                <div className="space-y-2">
                    <Label htmlFor="nombre">Nombre</Label>
                    <div className="relative">
                        <User className="absolute left-2 top-2.5 h-4 w-4 text-gray-500" />
                        <Input
                            id="nombre"
                            name="nombre"
                            className="pl-8"
                            defaultValue={contactoActual.nombre}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="space-y-2">
                    <Label htmlFor="correo">Correo</Label>
                    <div className="relative">
                        <Mail className="absolute left-2 top-2.5 h-4 w-4 text-gray-500" />
                        <Input
                            id="correo"
                            name="correo"
                            type="email"
                            className="pl-8"
                            defaultValue={contactoActual.correo}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="space-y-2">
                    <Label htmlFor="telefono">Teléfono</Label>
                    <div className="relative">
                        <Phone className="absolute left-2 top-2.5 h-4 w-4 text-gray-500" />
                        <Input
                            id="telefono"
                            name="telefono"
                            type="tel"
                            className="pl-8"
                            defaultValue={contactoActual.telefono}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="space-y-2">
                    <Label htmlFor="organization">Organización</Label>
                    <div className="relative">
                        <Building className="absolute left-2 top-2.5 h-4 w-4 text-gray-500 z-10" />
                        <Select name="organization" defaultValue={contactoActual.organizacion}>
                            <SelectTrigger className="pl-8">
                                <SelectValue placeholder="Selecciona una organización" />
                            </SelectTrigger>
                            <SelectContent>
                                {organizationsData.map((organizacion) => (
                                    <SelectItem key={organizacion.id} value={organizacion.id}>
                                        {organizacion.nombre}
                                    </SelectItem>
                                ))}
                            </SelectContent>
                        </Select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='w-full flex justify-end'>
                    <ButtonTheme
                        type="submit"
                        className='w-fit'
                    >
                        <Users className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                        Editar Contacto
                    </ButtonTheme>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}


Interaccion:


Parece que se debe computar un estado local y usar las propiedades value y onValueChange del select.
